# "Отжим" применительно к стиральным машинам

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Он всё равно *отж**и**м* и в этом случае? Или меняется ударение? Просто не припомню, чтобы так говорили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трудный вопрос!

**1. Хотя что же в нем трудного** – во всех орфоэпических словарях говорится, что **правильно – это отжИм,** вот только пояснений они не дают.

Пользователи  же смотрят  на вас честными глазами и тоже уверяют, что уж  они-то,  конечно же,  следуют норме – **только отжИм.**

Но я им не всегда  верю, чисто по логике.  Ведь  если существуют в речи два варианта произношения, то кто-то из них говорит неправильно – **Отжим.**

Чтобы разобраться в этом, нужен особо «извращенный» ум.

**2. Начнем со словаря Кузнецова** : Отжим, -а; м. Спец. (1-2, 4 зн.). О. влаги.  [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=отжать&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

Ударение на приставку? Специальный термин? Что ж, это уже неплохо.

**3. А теперь попробуем сравнить варианты:** отжать/отжаться и отозвать/отозваться, так как пара  «Отзыв и отзЫв» нам более понятна. [Вот](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2216657-kak-pravilno-stavitsja-udarenie-v-slove-otzyv.html) и статья интересная попалась.

**Лексема ОТЗЫ́В** связана с глаголами ОТЗЫВАТЬ, ОТОЗВАТЬ), то есть:
• возвращения потребовать (отзы́в рапорта; отзы́в работников из отпуска; отзы́в дипломата).

Лексема **О́ТЗЫВ** связана с глаголами **ОТЗЫВАТЬСЯ, ОТОЗВАТЬСЯ**; отзываться/отозваться можно:
• на чей-то зов,
• на условную фразу, то есть на пароль (узнать пароль и о́тзыв на него; забыть о́тзыв на пароль);
• на чьё-то чувство (найти о́тзыв в чьём-то сердце, о́тзыв на любовь);
• на книгу, фильм, спектакль.

**4. В итоге получается:**

(1) Машина отжимает воду из  белья – отжИм воды из белья (режим работы).

(2) Вода из белья  отжимаетСЯ машиной – Отжим воды из белья (процесс).

**5. Тогда нормой** считают название режима – отжИм. Ну а если результат работы неудовлетворительный, но  можно сделать дополнительный Отжим воды (наверное).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Шарон! Интересно очень, если действительно так и надо говорить. =)

Answer (score 0):

от-жи́м

*1)* сжатие, сдавливание, освобождение от воды, влаги.
*2)* жаргон - отъём чужого имущества или бизнеса с применением силы или угроз.

Comment: Ну я очень рад.

Comment: на приставку ОТ часто приходит ударение: отмель, отблеск, отсвет, отклик. Слово "отжИм" в этом случае смотрится как исключение.